# PID Controller in esp32 using Espressif-IDE

Tags: c, esp32, pid-controller, espressif-idf

Hi i want to learn how esp32 works. Now a days I'm working on **PID Controller in esp32** use **FreeRTOS** by default and for this I need to wrtie the whole **PID controller** by myself. I went through the documentation of esp32 but not really helpfull. I look to the [nuttx PID Controller code](https://github.com/apache/nuttx/commit/27fc3c959d5bfd047d96cae8d9de835b04f24654). I understand the code of **esp32_pid.h** but really don't know how to use it. for example i want to blink led in such a way that RED led blink for 5 sec and after that an interrupt occur and PID change and it turn on the BLUE led and then green. how I can do this what files i need to change. second I'll be glad if someone share the some documentation for the coding so i can learn from it.

NOTE: I did study the offical documentation.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do three things: 1) flash some LEDs in a particular order, 2) implement a PID, 3) something about an interrupt. Maybe you should try to solve one of these problems in isolation first. Either way, you should make some kind of attempt, and share your code if you get stuck. We can't tell you everything you need to do for all three of these problems.